# Why do I have two copies of the same script being runned by cron?

Tags: python, process, cron, ps

I have only one line devoted to the script I'm running every 15 minutes:

```
*/30 0-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * ~/env/bin/python2 ~/hasoffers_api/script.py > ~/hasoffers_api/logs/script_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```

The script itself is secured internally from running twice if the first instance haven't stopped working yet (script is written in Python):

```
def checkPidRunning(pid):
    global script_name
    if pid<1:
        print "Incorrect pid number!"
        exit()
        try:
            os.kill(pid, 0)
        except OSError:
            print "Abnormal termination of previous process."
            return False
    else:
        ps_command = "ps -p %s -o cmd h | grep %s" % (pid, script_name)
        # ipdb.set_trace()
        process_exist = os.system(ps_command)
        if process_exist == 0:
            return True
        else:
            print "Process with pid %s is not a Python process. Continue..." % pid
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_name = os.path.basename(__file__)
    pid = str(os.getpid())
    pidfile = os.path.join("/", "tmp/", script_name + ".pid")
    if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
        print "Warning! Pid file %s existing. Checking for process..." % pidfile
        r_pid = int(file(pidfile, 'r').readlines()[0])
        if checkPidRunning(r_pid):
            print "Python process with pid = %s is already running. Exit!" % r_pid
            exit()
        else:
            file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)
    else:
        file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)
    try:
        doing_stuff()
    finally:
        os.unlink(pidfile)
```

The question is:

**Why do I see the script being runned twice when I check it by ps aux | grep python:**

```
pavel     1502  0.0  0.0   4388   824 ?        Ss   09:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c ~/env/bin/python2 ~/hasoffers_api/scruot.py > ~/hasoffers_api/logs/script_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.log 2>&1
pavel     1541 26.9  1.9 2633524 159692 ?      Sl   09:00  16:55 /home/pavel/env/bin/python2 /home/pavel/hasoffers_api/script.py
```

The only detail - I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor pattern inside of the script, but it's threads, not processes...

Comment: try/exxept/raise  is nonsense. Delete that.

Comment: There's finally: os.unlink(pidfile) instead of except, my fault.